# Custom Linq Extension to replace For loop

Tags: linq, c#-3.0, lambda, extension-methods

```
public static void For<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Action<T, int> predicate)
    {
        using (IEnumerator<T> iterator = items.GetEnumerator())
        {
            int index = 0;
            while (iterator.MoveNext())
            {
                T item = iterator.Current;
                predicate(item, index);
                index++;
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm intesting in a linq extention to enumerate over a list and perform an action with the index of the collection - like a for loop.

then you can use the method like this

```
items.For((item, index) => item.Prop = item.Prop != MyMethod(index) ? MyMethod(index) : item.Prop);
```

Does this seem right?

Comment: Why are you using 2 while loops? The iterator.MoveNext() will always be false by the time you get to the second loop...

Comment: i edited my code, i was using skipwhile as an example

Comment: Note that you should probably change the name of the `Action` from `predicate` to something else.  A `Predicate` in C# specifically means a method that returns `true` or `false` - it's a boolean test.  In the code above, `predicate` is being used as an action to take upon an instance of `T` and the index of that item in your `IEnumerable<T>`.  Just plain `Action<T,int> action` might be more appropriate.

Comment: @mjd79 I warmly agree. Who on earth would reasonably call an `int` variable **string** ? You precisely do this kind of thing here (the only difference being of course this my analogy wouldn't even compile !) Once again for the sake of comprehension, the extension method in question is a well known recurrent demand which is anywhere else always referred to as **ForEach**, by analogy with the so named `List<..>`'s method which does exactly what you want. You might have been unaware of that, and thus it is not exactly an error... But your naming conventions are very bad practices all the same...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static void For<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Action<T, int> predicate)
{
    int i=0;
    foreach (T item in items)
    {
        predicate(item, i++);
    }
}
```

Comment: that seems pretty clean.  i'll take it.

Comment: Having multiple side effects on a single line is bad style, and doing it with post-increment (what I would consider a C-era trick) needlessly obfuscates the code.  Just add a line that makes it *explicit* where i is incremented, and which value is passed to predicate.

Comment: I dunno this seems pretty clear to me, where's the confusion?

Comment: @chris basically ruling out the use of *for (;;)*. I have no problem reading what is happening and basically finds it sad that too many programmers these days have a problem understanding i++ or ++i used directly in a method call.

Comment: @Greg: It confuses people, and since this site is as much about learning as giving answers, the answers should suggest good practices.  There is really *no value* in saving the line.  It isn't as if screen space or the few extra bytes cost anything at all.

Comment: @Pauli: I have dealt with seasoned programmers that introduced off by one errors in their code because they thought that for (;; i++) incremented i *after* the body of the loop.  It is no accident that most coding standards disallow i++ in favor of ++i, which is much easier to understand.

Comment: @Greg: I am not basing this off of optomization, I'm basing it off of the coding standards that I have been exposed to.  Both MISRA and the Joint Strike Fighter Standards explicitly disallow the use of side-effects like this in code.  I would not be surprised if every industry standard does so.

Comment: @Greg Downvoted for the horrendous breaking of all the wide accepted conventions : this extension method is a classic always referred to as ForEach, and I really can't deal with an Action delegate been called **predicate**. Aarrghh.

Comment: @Ssithra: Please post the perfect answer so we can all learn from you and absorb your brilliance :)

Comment: @Greg **You** posted the right answer, indeed. It is not a matter of brilliance nor even correctness, but of semantics. When you declare a variable of type `int`, I hope you will agree that it's really a very very poor idea to name this variable **string**, isn't it ? Here you declare a parameter of type `Action<...>` and you name it **predicate** whereas a `Predicate<...>` is a reserved word used to describe functions returning a `bool`, what you **predicate** variable is clearly not. Except if you explicitely intend to make your code hard to understand and maintain, it's a most bad practice.

Comment: @Ssithra: have a look at the question and you'll see that I've just followed the naming used by the OP.  Seriously, if you have an improvement to make, just edit the question or add a comment with your suggestions.  I appreciate your feedback but staring at the heavens and saying *Aarrghh* really isn't helping anyone - get some sleep :)

Comment: @Greg Oh ooh... obviously it's the OP which should have been aarrghhed at first from this point of view. Still think that leaving such bad things in your answer is detrimental to its quality (which is othewise beyond any doubt) but obviously the rot had set in from the beginning (the OP), which I had even not noticed : sure some sleep is needed ! :)

Comment: @Ssithra: No, no-one needed to be aarrghhed. Paragraphs of pedantic moaning and ranting are only reducing the quality/usefulness of the answer.  Have a look at the comment from @mjd79 for an example of a helpful contribution.

Comment: @Greg I must confess you're right. I'll try to always keep this exchange in mind if I happen to be tempted to aarrghh or blame someone again in the future. Thank you for **your** help.

Comment: Issues of semantics aside, I wonder what the performance of using such a variant of a 'For loop is. thanks, Bill

Comment: @BillW: No need to wonder, you can easily run performance test or compare the IL with other loop implementations :)  I think you'll find there is no (or trivial) performance impact.